# xparse bug in optional arguments (simply not working)?

Tags: xparse

The follow code returns `-NoValue-` instead of `3`

It seems I'm wrong in that I thought xparse took a single argument and parsed it instead of all the arguments of a macro.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book} % use larger type; default would be 10pt


\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\Dotparse}{o m} { #1 }

% Passes each value in the array to an xparse command.
\def\Dots#1
{
    \foreach \n in {#1}{
        \Dotparse{\n}
}}

\Dots{[3]f4s3,f12s5,s2f14,[5]e,f,g,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, `\Dotparse[3]{f4s3}` prints `3`. `\Dotparse{[3]f4s3}` has no optional argument. `:)`

Comment: Ok, That makes sense... I simplified this example and didn't think about it. I'll post the full code. Actually, I had a misconception about xparse. I thought it took an argument and parsed it given the specification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all this is no bug. You defined a command `\Dotparse` with one mandatory and one optional argument.

The mandatory argument is braced by curly brackets `{....}` and the optional one by square brackets `[...]`.

If you type `\Dotparse{[3]f4s3}` LaTeX reads only one mandatory argument because the outer brackets are `{...}`. So the correct form is `\Dotparse[3]{f4s3}` to set the optional and the mandatory argument.

The output `-NoValue` is a special key provided by `xparse`. `xparse` provides several optional argument types whereby `o` has the following meaning:

- If no optional argument without square brackets is given the argument is set to `\NoValue`.
- If square brackets are given the argument is set to this value.

Note: An empty optional arguments doesn't set `\NoValue`.

Based on this information you can use the conditional `\IfNoValueTF` to test whether an optional argument is given or not.

**EDIT**
I can't understand your question. But your example looks really weird for me. *You should tell us what's your intention.*

You can do the following:

1. Every definition of macros and functions should be done in the header.
2. The variable `\n` must be expanded before the function `\Dotparse` works
3. You need not to use extra brackets around the variable `n`.
4. Use the argument type `u` which has the following syntax

   ```
   u<token>
   ```

   this argument type reads everything until the given token is found whereby the given token isn't part of the argument. I used the token `\nil`.

The whole example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\Dotparse}{o u \nil } {#1\textbullet }
\def\Dots#1
{
    \foreach \n in {#1}{
     \n\qquad \expandafter\Dotparse\n\nil \par
}}
\begin{document}
\Dots{[3]f4s3,f12s5,s2f14,[5]e,f,g,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2:**

@BrunoLeFloch suggested an alternative using `\clist_map_inline:Nn`. In this way you don't need the package `pgffor` and you don't  regard any expansion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Dotparse}{o u \nil } 
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {no~optional~Argument~given}
   {The~optional~argument~is~#1}
   \par
 }
\clist_new:N \l_dot_store_clist
\NewDocumentCommand{\Dots}{ m }
 {
 \clist_set:Nn \l_dot_store_clist { #1 }
 \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_dot_store_clist
   {
     \Dotparse ##1 \nil 
   }
 }  
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\Dots{[3]f4s3,f12s5,s2f14,[5]e,f,g,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does `\nil` do?

Comment: @Tobi: `\nil` is a single token and the argument type `u` reads everything until the given token is found. You can also use `\hippopotamus` ;-)

Comment: Instead of `\foreach` I'd use `\SplitList` and `\tl_map_inline`, or directly `\clist_map_inline`.  That avoids loading `pgffor`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: You mean as an alternativ of the algorithm of the OP. The benefit I can avoid the `expandafter` ;-)

Comment: @Marco: Indeed.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: What do you think about the new example?

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I thought it is a TeX primitive …

Comment: Your answer is very complete.  One small improvement is that you don't need to store the clist in a temporary variable: just use `\clist_map_inline:nn {#1}{\Dotparse ##1\nil}`.  As for the choice of syntax of the OP, well, let's simply dub it "non-standard".

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I was under the impression that xparse parsed 
"strings" so a string argument to a macro like \Dots{xyz}, xyz would be parsed to the specification. Now I see that xparse really just rewrites the macro definition. This is not what I want because I want to take a certain *STRING* and turn it into a macro(I'll write a post that clarifies what I'm after)